# How to execute selenium script in a lot of threads?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, java-threads

I like to test my site in a lot of threads. But when I trying to do that, I see one problem. All motions when I like are happening in last opened window. So, the first window just stuck in background.

```
public class Core extends Thread{

    private static FirefoxDriver firefoxDriver;

    public Core(){
        firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        firefoxDriver.get("https://google.com/");
        firefoxDriver.close();
    }
}

public class Main {
  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/riki/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64/geckodriver");

        Core core = new Core();
        Core core2 = new Core();

        core.start();    // This thread is stuck in back
        core2.start();   // This thread goes to google.com twice
    }
}
```

I really don't understand why it happens. You can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvckm.png). After that the code has run, the first window keeps hanging in back. It don't close. When the second thread closes after executing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of you using static field for Forefox driver.

Static means the one per all instances. So remove `static` here.

```
private FirefoxDriver firefoxDriver;
```

and after, each thread will use it's own `firefoxDriver` field.

Static fields should be used carefully if you going to modify them.